# Get rule condition and other details in checkout

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules

Not getting description and condition, can you help me in this if there is any way to get rule condition and other details

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$rule=$objectManager->create('Magento\SalesRule\Model\RuleRepository');
$rule = $this->ruleRepository->getById(1);


echo $rule->getDescription();
echo $rule->getCondition();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$ruleId = 1;
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$rule = $objectManager->create('Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule')->load($ruleId);

echo "<pre>"; print_r($rule->getData()); exit;
```